# Is there any gem/plugin available to create your own url shortener service using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, url-shortener

I want to create a service for url shorten for my own project.Basically I am sending some information via sms, so thats why I need to shorten the URL. I don't want to use google url shortner or some other services available.

We want to have our own custom url shortner.

Is there any gem or plugin available for this for rails, something like this

```
 short_url = plugin_function_with_some_configurations(long_url)
 long_url = plugin_function_with_some_configurations(short_url)
```

as from google search i came to know many of those written in PHP.

Comment: Have you seen the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338870/how-to-implement-a-short-url-like-urls-in-twitter/6340547#6340547?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several.

You should check: https://github.com/search?type=Everything&language=Ruby&q=url+shortener

or https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=shortener