# Creating a shortened URL for all objects in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I would like to display a shortened URL besides the content items on my site for ease of sharing.

What would be the most efficient way of doing so, and are there any suitable gems / libraries?

I am using rails on a mongodb/mongoid stack

[image]

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338870/how-to-implement-a-short-url-like-urls-in-twitter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be simple enough (regardless if you are on Mongo / MySQL or anything else). what you need is a small collection (mongo if i may) that holds some kind of an MD5 hash of the real url you are after and the real url itself, for example:

```
ShortLink.create(:hash_link => Digest::MD5.hexdigest(resource_url(@resource)), :real_link => resource_url(@resource))
```

I suggest adding another route that catches those like this:

```
match "l/:key", "ShortLinks#show"
```

should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use bitly gem to shorten your URL.

The following link helps you to configure bitly:

http://www.marketingformavens.com/blog/url-shortening-bitly-ruby-on-rails