# Is it possible to base 36 encode with JavaScript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm thinking about using the encode/decode technique here (Encoding to base 36/decoding from base 36 is simple in Ruby)

[how to implement a short url like urls in twitter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338870/how-to-implement-a-short-url-like-urls-in-twitter)

Idea being to track user referrals, invite URLs. I can use Rails to decode, but it there a way to encode with Javascript or jQuery?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The `toString` method on `Number` has an optional argument of radix:

```
(128482).toString(36);
128482..toString(36);
128482 .toString(36);
var num = 128482; num.toString(36);
```

Note this doesn't work, because numbers expect decimal digits after a period, not letters:

```
128482.toString(36);  // Syntax error
```

Also, you can decode with JS as well:

```
parseInt("2r4y", 36);
```

EDIT:

> But if I want to remove look-alike characters (1-l or 0-O) what can I do?

The easiest is to reduce the base by number of characters you're skipping, then make a translation: Note that only one of `1-l` or `0-O` is a problem, since base36 encodes only lowercase (in which case you have `1-l`, but not `0-O`) which you can make uppercase (in which case, vice versa).

```
(128482).toString(36).replace(/[m-y]/, x => String.fromCharCode(x.charCodeAt(0) + 1))
```

If you want to have a base larger than 36, you would have to have your own base-changing function, as 36 is as high as `toString` supports. In that case, it is easy enough to make your own digit inventory as you want.

> for working with long numbers?

Go ahead :) Note the `n` suffix that turns the number into [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt):

```
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000n.toString(36)
// => "9edwccv83mch429oxmlxupo4z1bdaiusrm29s"
```

Comment: As for why `128482.toString(36)` doesn't work, but `128482..toString(36)` (note the two dots) does...JS likes to snarf the first dot for the number whenever it can, and `128482.` is a valid number literal, even without anything after the decimal point.

Comment: * Possible loss of accuracy for numbers greater than 2^53

Comment: This is good, But if I want to remove look-alike characters (1-l or 0-O) what can I do? and for working with long numbers?

Answer (score 7):

For anyone looking for how to encode a *string* in base36 (since this question, [How do i convert string to base36 in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28512362/how-do-i-convert-string-to-base36-in-javascript) , is redirected here) -

Here's what I came up with.

```
/* encode / decode strings to / from base36 

   based on: http://snipplr.com/view/12653/
*/

var base36 = {
    encode: function (str) {
        return Array.prototype.map.call(str, function (c) {
            return c.charCodeAt(0).toString(36);
        }).join("");
    },
    decode: function (str) {
        //assumes one character base36 strings have been zero padded by encodeAscii
        var chunked = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i = i + 2) {
            chunked[i] = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(str[i] + str[i + 1], 36));
        }
        return chunked.join("");
    },
    encodeAscii: function (str) {
        return Array.prototype.map.call(str, function (c) {
            var b36 = base36.encode(c, "");
            if (b36.length === 1) {
                b36 = "0" + b36;
            }
            return b36;
        }).join("")
    },
    decodeAscii: function (str) {
        //ignores special characters/seperators if they're included
        return str.replace(/[a-z0-9]{2}/gi, function (s) {
            return base36.decode(s);
        })
    }
};

var foo = "a-Az-Z 0-9 !@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]};:',<.>/?`~";
var bar = base36.encodeAscii(foo);

console.log(foo);
console.log(base36.decode(bar));

console.log('');

var bar = "==/" + bar + "\\==";
console.log(bar)
console.log(base36.decodeAscii(bar));


//doesn't work
console.log('');
var myString = "some string";
var myNum = parseInt(myString, 36);
console.log(myNum.toString(36))

myString = "FooBarW000t";
myNum = parseInt(myString, 36);
console.log(myNum.toString(36))

myString = "aAzZ09!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]};:',<.>/?`~";
myNum = parseInt(myString, 36);
console.log(myNum.toString(36))

/* 
Outputs:

a-Az-Z 0-9 !@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]};:',<.>/?`~
a-Az-Z 0-9 !@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]};:',<.>/?`~

==/2p191t3e192i0w1c191l0w0x1s0z10112m12161415192n1p172j3f2l3h1n1m13181o1a1q1b1r2o3i\==
==/a-Az-Z 0-9 !@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]};:',<.>/?`~\==

some
foobarw000w
aazz09
*/
```

Comment: What kind of strings are accepted? A string can be anything.

Comment: Also: this seems to always use 2 characters per character. This is great, but it doesn't provide any length advantages; you might as well use hexadecimals.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this baseXY shortener, designed for a very similar question/need I had:

https://github.com/marko-36/base29-shortener.

- By default, in order to leave out easily interchangeable characters, it is a base**29** shortener, but the '*XY*' number is the same as number of characters you decide to use for encoding.
- Since the set of characters is fully customizable, you can omit any you wish (*i, l, 1, L, o, 0, O*..)
- To make it less obvious, what the encoding character set is, and/or if you want the encoding string to have a minimal length, just start encoding from a high enough number.

This is it, hope it helps:

```
    const c=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']; 
    //characters for encoding

    function to29(i){
        var sLen = Math.floor(Math.log(i)/Math.log(c.length)) +1;
        var s = '';
        for(ex=sLen-1; ex>-1; --ex){
            s += c[Math.floor(i / Math.pow(c.length,ex))];
            i = [i % Math.pow(c.length,ex)];
        }
        return s;
    }

    function from29(s){
        var i = 0;
        for (ex=0; ex<s.length; ++ex){
            i += c.indexOf(s.substring(ex,ex+1))*Math.pow(c.length,s.length-1-ex);
        }
        return i;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to decode @imjosh's answer in python (say if you've encoded client-side and need to decode server-side), this is what I used.  I would have left as a comment in @imjosh's answer but comments don't format very well.

```
def decodeBase36(str):
  decoded_str = ""
  for i in range(0, len(str), 2):
    char = chr(int(str[i:i+2], 36))
    decoded_str += char
  return decoded_str
```

and a not-as-elegant Objective-C version:

```
+ (NSString *)b36DecodeString:(NSString *)b36String
{
    NSMutableString *decodedString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@""];
    for (int i = 0; i < [b36String length]; i+=2) {
        NSString *b36Char = [b36String substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 2)];
        int asciiCode = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            int v = [b36Char characterAtIndex:j];
            asciiCode += ((v < 65) ? (v - 48) : (v - 97 + 10)) * (int)pow(36, 1 - j);
        }
        [decodedString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", asciiCode]];
    }
    return decodedString;
}
```

Comment: Please specify what the function does and what kind of inputs are expected. As it is, this is a code only answer.