# How do I convert string to base36 in javascript

Tags: javascript

`var sVar = "someString";`

I tried `sVar.toString(36)` as inferred from `num.toString(2)`. But it doesn't work.

I know to convert from base64 you use atob/btoa but I could not find for base 36. Maybe there is a variant for this that does it?

Comment: string to base36... `sVar` has string

Comment: What is the value of `sVar` here?

Comment: I want to convert **"string"** to Base36

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate.  The linked question is how to convert a base 10 number to base 36.  This question is on how to convert a string to a base 36 number. Two different questions that have two different answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert a string to a base-36 integer.

```
var myString = "somestring";
var myNum = parseInt(myString, 36); /* 2913141654103084 */
```

And you can use [`.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) to convert back to a string.

```
myNum.toString(36) /* "somestring" */
```

Both functions take a numeric "radix" (an integer between 2 and 36 specifying the base to use for representing numeric values) as a parameter, which should be `36` for base-36.

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/dev/api#fullnames according to this i should have gotten `15bfi0` for string `aww` .. can you explain it..

Comment: but i get this `14144`

Comment: that code only works on some strings.  e.g. decode36(encode36("FooBarW000t")) -> foobarw000w

Comment: ok the problem was that reddit converts integer id into base36 NOT the name of the subreddit.