# am I exposing sensitive data if I put a bson ID in a url?

Tags: mongodb, url, bson

Say I have a Products array in my Mongodb. I'd like users to be able to see each product on their own page: `http://www.mysite.com/product/12345/Widget-Wodget`. Since each Product doesn't have an incremental integer ID (12345) but instead it has a BSON ID (5063a36bdeb13f7505000630), I'd need to either add the integer ID or use the BSON ID.

Since BSON ID's include the PID:

- 4-byte timestamp,
- 3-byte machine identifier,
- 2-byte process id,
- 3-byte counter.

Am I exposing secure information to the outside world if I use the BSON ID in my url?

Comment: The way I do is, I usually encode the bson id to base62, that too just for URL shortening. But as far as I know no significant issue can arise by doing so.

Comment: @SushantGupta relevant, in that case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338870/how-to-implement-a-short-url-like-urls-in-twitter

Comment: Yeah, that works fine. But the way I do, I don't have to maintain a database or collection just for my url shortening. Its a quick method. By far I haven't came across any security issue as well :)

Comment: I think the machine ID and process ID are hashed anyways. As for the timestamp and counter, those aren't very sensitive. But your ObjectID's are predictable, so I wouldn't use them to hide sensitive pages.

Comment: Oh yes, I use BSON ID for pages I wish to keep public. Obviously not for private sensitive pages :)

Comment: I don't see any real security threats here, I am not sure how useful the information within the BSON id is for a person who hasn't physically hacked your computer, in which case your screwed anyway. They can't even use the machine id since it isn't publicly broadcasted through the network interface, so all information in the BSON id useless really, fair enough if it is revealing, in a small glimmer but not very much.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I can't think of any use to gain privileges on your machines, however using ObjectIds everywhere discloses a lot of information nonetheless.

By crawling your website, one could:

- find about some hidden objects: for instance, if the counter part goes from 0x....b1 to 0x....b9  between times t1 and t2, one can guess ObjectIds within these invervals. However, guessing ids is most likely useless if you enforce access permissions
- know the signup date of each user (not very sensitive info but better than nothing)
- deduce actual (as opposed to publicly available) business hours from the timestamps of objects created by the staff
- deduce in which timezones your audience lives from the timestamps of user-generated objects: if your website is one which people use mostly at lunchtime, then one could measure peaks of ObjectIds and deduce that a peak at 8 PM UTC means the audience was on the US West coast
- and more generally, by crawling most of your website, one can build a timeline of the success of your service, having for any given time knowledge of: your user count, levels of user engagement, how many servers you've got, how often your servers are restarted. PID changes occurring on weekends are more likely crashes, whereas those on business days are more likely crashes + software revisions
- and probably find other info specific to your business processes and domain

To be fair, even with random ids one can infer a lot. The main issue is that you need to prevent anyone from scraping a statistically significant part of your site. But if someone is determined, they'll succeed eventually, which is why providing them with all of this extra, timestamped info seems wrong.

Comment: I don't understand about hidden objects, also you can deduce business hours by looking at what times you can contact the company, most companies should display business hours on their site freely. IDs are made server side so they are server time, not client time. How can they build a timeline from your BSON id? there is no way to predict overall what the id tells about the database or the severs. How can they tell how many times you restarted without querying every single id even the deleted ones?

Comment: I get the first point slightly but that's one that exists with an incrementing id as well and should be solved by RBAM but I still don't get the others, especially on a e-commerce site, unless everyone lies about when they are available. Also the signup date of each user on most sites is useless since sites like google, facebook, youtube and so many others show when the user signed up in true date form, so those stats are easier to scrap there. User generated objects will still have a serer-side objectid so I still don't see that.

Comment: I still don't understand the 5th point either since they would have to query every single objectid including ones that no longer exist on the system in order to understand that, otherwise they are getting inacurate results from their crawls. You can't even detect if a objectid, on it's own, is a user object or a product object so you can't just crawl all objectids, it is easier to understand if they were to just use SEO friendly urls than plain objectids.

Comment: Sorry to spam like this I am just thinking of more things, another thing is that due to the formation of the objectid it isn't sequential which means that unlike an auto incrementing id you cannot predict the next _id in the chain reliably which means crawling by object id for a particular object (i.e. user or page_click) is quite difficult, if not very doable.

Comment: (1) I wouldn't compare ObjectIds vs. incrementing ids but rather ObjectIds vs. random ids which disclose less info
(2) Not all sites publish signup dates. If yours doesn't, it would be a mistake to use ObjectIds as user ids
(3) About business hours, I tried to think of clever uses but I couldn't. Maybe you're right
(5) Statistics allow to draw conclusions from a limited sample, I don't understand your objection, especially about deleted objects. If crawling your site gives a large number of ids from URLs or the HTML, then you can graph user growth, server counts and restarts accurately enough

Comment: Well a random id still time based so you still have the same problem. You could encode the string but that just gives an extra layer really, no real defense against scraping. Yea true if you don't wanna display user sign up date it could have an effect there, about 5 I guess it just comes from the fact that I can't see how some one would go abot crawling the site in a manner that would give meaningful results.

Comment: I can understand server restarts since you can do that with normal spidering, but I can't grasp how the other statistics could be gathered, it seems really out of reach of non-contextual crawl bots.

Comment: My definition of a random id is it is made by a cryptographically-secure [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRNG) and then it is checked for uniqueness. It is not time-based as you say. I still don't understand your objection about (5). [Confidence intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) show that you can determine your margins of error. Once you've crawled enough pages, you reach accurate results. Then you can guess some revenues from user count and engagement, and some expenses from server counts

Comment: "how the stats could be gathered?" Crawl a large part of the site. You obtain thousands of URLs such as user profiles (eg /user/abcd1234), user-generated content (eg /posts/dcba4321), form data (reply to comment ef567890), etc. Since these ids are all timestamped and typed by the URL/form (such id is a user, such is a post, etc.), you can graph each type through time. I'll admit that posts and comments are always timestamped anyway but not users and some other classes of objects.

Comment: Hmm the average unique id is time based for a reason due to relative uniqueness without having to query it but ok, anyway thinking about it more you can predict how much traffic a site might have got but but I definitely don't see how you can get server count from the _id, considering that the _id is made in the app so the server count won't be realiable, i.e. you could have one app server and 7 db severs. But yea you could graph the amount of top level entites someone might have.

Comment: "anyway thinking about it more you can predict how much traffic a site might have got" In comparison to your unique id.

Comment: To get around these issues you'd need to come up with a highly random way to make object ids that is also unique across multiple databases. On the other hand, you're exposing _some_ information to a determined attacker (?). The perils of the first part seem to outweigh the perils of the second part.

Comment: @jcollum: "highly random way to make object ids that is also unique across multiple databases": random is the job of /dev/urandom and unique is easy if this id is a sharding key. I agree is it impossible not to expose any information, but I understood your question as a puzzle

Comment: ObjectIDs are normally generated by the client driver rather than the server .. so your inferences on server restarts and usefulness of PIDs are incorrect.  The use case described is also product URLs rather than user IDs, so there is generally less interesting behaviour to infer. If someone can access a "hidden" resource because they can guess or find an ID, the fundamental problem that the resource is not properly secured ;-).

Comment: @Stennie: The client driver runs on a web/API/whatever-you-call-it server, which is useful to be able to count. Plus, if you insert an object without an id, I'm not sure which one of the client driver or mongod generates it, but it may be mongod, I haven't checked. I agree product URLs are not that useful but once you publish these, it is tempting to use ObjectIds everywhere. Agreed on blocking access to resources

Comment: The client API generates the objectid not mongod, it is designed specifically to create a high level of randomness without needing to have the over head of checking its uniqueness against the database which will crawl inserts on a system.

Answer (score 2):

Sharing the information in the [ObjectID](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/object-id/) will not compromise your security.  Someone could infer minor details such as when the ObjectID was created (timestamp), but none of the ObjectID components should be tied to authentication or authorization.

If you are building an e-commerce site, SEO is typically a strong consideration for public URLs.  In this case you normally want to use a friendlier URL with shorter and more semantic path components than an ObjectID.

Note that you do not have to use the default ObjectID for your `_id` field .. so could always generate something more relevant for your application.  The default ObjectID does provide a reasonable guarantee of uniqueness, so if you implement your own `_id` allocation you will have to take this into consideration.

See also:

- [Create an Auto-Incrementing Sequence Field](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/)

Answer (score 2):

As @Stennie said, not really.

Let's start with the pid, most hackers wouldn't bother looking for a pid, on say Linux, instead they would just do:

```
ps aux | grep mongod
```

or something similar. Of course this requires the hacker to have actually hacked your server, I know of no public hack available based on the pid alone. Considering the pid will change when you restart the machine or `mongod`, this information is utterly useless to anyone trying to spy.

The machine id is another bit of data that is quite useless publicly and, to be honest, they would get a better understanding of your network using `ping` or `digg` than they would through the machine id alone.

So to answer the question: No, there is no real security threat and the information you are displaying is of no use to anyone except MongoDB really.

I also agree with @Stennie on using SEO friendly URLs, an example which I commonly use for e-commerce is `/product/product_title_` with a smaller random id (maybe base 64 encode the `_id`) or a auto incrementing id with `.html` on the end.

Comment: ObjectIDs are normally generated by the driver (not the MongoDB server) so the information (PIDs, etc) would relate to the application rather than MongoDB. Different processes (eg. Apache worker threads) will vary the PID so you can't make a reliable inference that PIDs relate to server restarts.