# shorten url in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my routes.rb file i have like below

```
get 'homes-detail/*property_slug',
      to: 'property_details#show',
      as: :property_details, format: false,
      constraints: IgnoreSpecialCharactersConstraint.new(:property_slug, false, "&")
  end
```

I am doing redirect_to show page of the property page like this.

```
url = property_details_path(property_slug: permalink_slug, prop_status: @property.property_status)
redirect_to((url),
        status: 301
      )
```

But when the browser reloads it loads the page with query params like below.

```
http://localhost:3000/homes-detail/100-Bresco-CIpolo_TX_UXC7678C-71211?prop_status=for_rent
```

But i need to remove prop_status=for_rent from the above url and return only

```
http://localhost:3000/homes-detail/100-Bresco-CIpolo_TX_UXC7678C-71211
```

How can i do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338870/how-to-implement-a-short-url-like-urls-in-twitter

Comment: If you don't want query params submitted in the url you'll need to change your route to a 'post' instead of a 'get' in your routes file.